# VirtualStringTree (via GetIt) syntax error from compiler in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-11-alexandria, tvirtualstringtree

Just installed D11 and VirtualStringTree from GetIt. Couple of problems when trying to port a project over:

1. Had to manually add `uses VirtualTrees.Header` to get the following statement to compile:

   ```pascal
   VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options := VirtualStringTree1.Header.Options + [hoVisible]
   ```

   Don't remember having to do this before.
2. Now for the question. This code won't compile:

   ```pascal
   VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[0].Options := 
   VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[0].Options + [coVisible];
   ```

   Error is:

   > E2003 Undeclared identifier 'coVisible'

Comment: One solution is to also add `VirtualTrees.Types` to the Uses.

Comment: Probably that is worth reading: https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView/wiki/Breaking-Changes-in-upcoming-V8

Answer (score 0):

Both comments (@Brian and @dwrbudr) are good answers to the question. From JAM-Software (JAM-Software) **Breaking Changes in upcoming V8**:

> Simple types, enums and constants have been extracted to the unit
> VirtualTrees.Types. In case you get a compiler error undeclared
> identifier, it is usually sufficient to add the unit
> VirtualTrees.Types to the uses clause. This breaking change will be
> frequently encountered. For enum you can also turn them into scoped
> enums.

Other code breaking changes in version 8 may be found at  https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView/wiki/Breaking-Changes-in-upcoming-V8

Moderator: Please give credit to @dwrbudr for this answer.